# How do jquery live validate on dynamic fileld in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, livevalidation

I give same class name for dynamic and static field.its not working and i got this error

**Uncaught Error: LiveValidation::initialize - No element with reference or id of 'parent_first_name' exists!**

how can fixed it.I have try to override id name for dynamic field & static field.Id override only static field but not override for dynamic field. How do live validate dynamic field? please help me

Here my validation.js file.Bellow i mentioned one field only

```
  if($(".parent_first_name").length > 0) {
     var myparent_first_name = new LiveValidation('parent_first_name', { onlyOnBlur: true });
     myparent_first_name.add( Validate.Presence );

   }
```

Here my form.html.erb file.Bellow i mentioned one field only

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= p.text_field :first_name , :class => "parent_first_name" %>
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
<div class="field">
    <%= p.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= p.text_field(:first_name , :class => "parent_first_name") %>
  </div>`
```

just added the Parentheses

Comment: sorry friend! i tried ur answer but not working i got same error. thanks for ur help